# ETH red from choise wallet owned by myself gone out of my wallet and not arrived

Tags: ether, ethereum-classic, scam

I transferred roughly 8 ETH from my Choise wallet to another address owned by myself three days ago but the ETH has not turned up but has gone out of my choise wallet - the transaction Id does not exist on etherscan.io and the choise customer service (used loosely) are useless! Can anyone help? Supposed txn id

ae13f12d-c237-4318-9586-f08d66da8531

Is choise crypto/crypterium a scam?

Comment: Did you search for your addresss in a block explorer? That id isn't a valid transaction id in neither ethereum not ethereum classic.